# Mercurial showing files as modified incorrectly in Windows XP but not on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mercurial, windows-xp, tortoisehg

I'm using Tortoise 2.4.2 and I have a strange issue:

- on Windows 7 when cloning repository X from server everything is well
- on XP when cloning repository X from server I get some files modified although they are not modified

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038734/how-to-revert-unchanged-files-with-mercurial), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464824/mercurial-marks-unmodified-files-as-modified-in-working-directory-and-fails-to-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540228/diffing-a-file-against-last-mercurial-changeset-should-it-be-different) without success.

On XP when I try to do a diff I get no difference (binary equal).

Has someone experienced this issue and is there a solution for this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Are these *some files* the same each time you try cloning the repository X afresh on Windows XP?

Comment: @smoothreggae Yes, they are the same.

Comment: without knowing what they are, I can only ask: do you see a pattern in the kind of files that TortoiseHg thinks are modified?

Comment: @smoothreggae No ... They are ordinary source files. Their line ending is the same in each line... no difference (binary equal when launching kdiff3)

Comment: is upgrading TortoiseHg an option? I have been using 2.5 without any such problems

Comment: @smoothreggae The problem was found. See my answer below. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the **mercurial.ini** file contained some unwanted options. It had activated the **eol** extension but at [eol] section there was an extra option that created the unwanted behavior on Windows XP (this was not present on Windows 7).

Hope this saves some neurons in the future.

```
[eol]
;only-consistent = False
; the previous line should be commented and the repository re-cloned
```

Comment: aah :) I should have considered settings in `mercurial.ini`; [here](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2010-October/025699.html)'s a discussion that might help